# In Unix shell, how to convert from hex string to stdout bytes in machine-endian order

Tags: bash, shell, hex, endianness, xxd

I'd like to run a command similar to:

```
# echo 00: 0123456789abcdef | xxd -r | od -tx1
0000000 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
0000010
```

That is, I'd like to input a hex string and have it converted to bytes on stdout.  However, I'd like it to respect byte order of the machine I'm on, which is little endian.  Here's the proof:

```
# lscpu | grep Byte.Order
Byte Order:            Little Endian
```

So, I'd like it to work as above if my machine was big-endian.  But since it isn't, I'd like to see:

```
# <something different here> | od -tx1
0000000 ef cd ab 89 67 45 23 01
0000010
```

Now, xxd has a "-e" option for little endianess.  But 1) I want machine endianess, because I'd like something that works on big or little endian machines, and 2) "-e" isn't support with "-r" anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this —

```
$ echo 00: 0123456789abcdef | xxd -r | xxd -g 8 -e | xxd -r | od -tx1
0000000    ef  cd  ab  89  67  45  23  01
0000010
```

---

According to `man xxd`:

> - -e
>
>   Switch to **little-endian** hexdump.  This option treats byte groups  as  words  in  little-endian byte  order.   The  default  grouping  of  `4`  bytes may be changed using `-g`.  This option only applies to hexdump, leaving the ASCII (or EBCDIC) representation unchanged.  The command  line switches `-r`, `-p`, `-i` do not work with this mode.
> - -g *bytes* | -groupsize *bytes*
>
>   Separate  the output of every *bytes* bytes (two hex characters or eight bit-digits each) by a whitespace.  Specify `-g 0` to suppress grouping.  *Bytes* defaults to `2` in normal  mode,  `4`  in little-endian  mode  and  `1`  in  bits  mode.  Grouping does not apply to *postscript* or *include* style.

Comment: Sorry - I may have been unclear in the description.  I need the bytes out to be binary - that is, I only have the `od -tx1` in my example so that I can show what I'm expecting on output...